# Как установить npm пакет в web?

Tags: vue.js, npm

У меня есть сайт, работает на php +VUE

там VUE просто подключен через `<script src="vue.js">` (нету nodejs)

Я хочу воспользоваться этим плагином для VUE [vue-phone-mask-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-phone-mask-input) но не понимаю как его подключить через `<script src...`

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-phone-mask-input?activeTab=explore вот же исходники, подключайте как захотите...

Comment: Если разработчик пакета не опубликовал в облаке скрипт для подключения в браузере, то никак. Либо делать самому, либо собирать страницу сборщиком(что бы можно было подключать пакеты), либо как указано выше, берите исходники и их вставляйте в ваш сайт